# What does "ap" of \/ in Scalaz do?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I am looking at [disjunction](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Either.scala) type of scalaz and I noticed method `ap`

```
  /** Apply a function in the environment of the right of this disjunction. */
  def ap[AA >: A, C](f: => AA \/ (B => C)): (AA \/ C) =
    f flatMap (ff => map(ff(_)))
```

I guess I understand what it does. Now I wonder when and why one should actually use it ? Are there any examples of using this `ap` function ?

Answer (score 4):

The disjunction you are looking for:

```
import scalaz.{ \/, -\/ \/-, EitherT }
import scalaz.syntax.ToIdOps

object Testing extends ToIdOps // left and right methods come from there {
  // say you have the following method
  def someMethod(flag: Boolean): \/[Exception, SomeObject] {
    if (flag) someObj.right else new Exception("this is a sample").left
  }
}

// pattern matching
val x = someMethod match {
  case \/-(right) => // this is someObject
  case -\/(err) => // deal with the error  
}

// catamorphism
def methodThatDealsWithObj(obj: someObject)
def methodThatDealsWithErr(err: Exception)
someMethod.fold(methodThatDealsWithObj)(methodThatDealsWithErr)

// for comprehensions
// ap behaves just like EitherT.
for {
  correctResponse <- EitherT(someMethod)
}
```

**Update**

To understand how `EitherT` and `ap` works, think of an `Option`, which has `Some` and `None` and potential matches. With an `Option`, you would do:

```
for {
  a <- someOption
} yield ..
```

With `scalaz.\/`, you usually put an `Exception` on the left and a "correct" return type on the right. `ap` is a function that says apply this if the either has the correct type.

```
for {
  correctResponse <- ap(someEitherReturnMethod)
}
```

**Use cases**

The most common things I can think off where I use them avidly is complex asynchronous flows, such as OAuth1 or OAuth2, where I care about fine grained chaining of errors.

You can use `\/` as the return of a `Future`:

```
def someComplexThirdPartyApiCall: Future[\/[Exception, CorrectReturn]] = {
}
```

Because you can `flatMap` over futures, you can chain a couple methods like the above, collect and propagate errors.

**Example**

```
  def method1: Future[\/[Exception, String]]
  def method2(result: String): Future[\/[Exception, String]]

  def chainExample: Future[\/[Exception, Int]] = {
    for {
      firstResult <- EitherT(method1)
      secondResult <- EitherT(method2(firstResult))
    } yield secondResult.toInt
  }
```

Comment: Thank you ! Could explain please how `ap behaves just like EitherT` ? Why should one use `EitherT` in the first place ?

Comment: Thank you for the update. I am starting getting it ... Suppose I have `f1: A => Future[\/[Exception, B]` and `f2: B => Future[\/[Exception, C]]` how exactly can I compose them with `\/.ap` to get `f3:A => Future[\/[Exception, C]`?

Comment: @Michael You have `map` and `flatMap`.

Comment: Could you give an example of composing `f1` and `f2` to create `f3` (as those functions defined in the comment above) ?

Comment: @Michael Updated with example.

Comment: Thank. Could you explain where exactly `ap` is used in this example ?

Comment: @Michael It's not directly visible, however it's the thing that says do the action only if the result "is a right".

Comment: Thanks. I will think it over again.