# failure in Scala future's for comprehension

Tags: scala, future

I have three sequential Futures and use in the for comprehension like this

```
val comF = for {
  f1 <- future1
  f2 <- future2
  f3 <- future3
} yield {
  // something
}

comF onSuccess { }
comF onFailure { 
  // ----------------      Here is the problem  --------------------------------
  //
  // How do I know which future failed(throw exception), when the callback comes here ?
  // Thanks for the help! Different futures using different exceptions can solve it.
}
```

Now I have a future list like List[Future[T]], and first I transfer it to Future[List[T]] using this method ([Why does this list-of-futures to future-of-list transformation compile and work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307175/why-does-this-list-of-futures-to-future-of-list-transformation-compile-and-work)). then I get the future

```
val fList: Future[List[T]]
fList on Failure {
  // 
  // How do I know which is Fail now >??
}
```

Comment: If each of your futures throws different exceptions, then you can use pattern matching on your onFailure callback.

Comment: And if they're the same, then well, you can't. At least not with this for comprehension. Perhaps if you explain a little more, someone can provide a work around.

Comment: To convert `List[Future[T]]` to `Future[List[T]]` use [`Future.sequence`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$)

Comment: yet the situation doesn't change, you can do `try { List(maybeThrow1, maybeThrows2, maybeThrows3 } catch (...` and you still don't know which computation failed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the code:

```
def func = {
  try {
    val x = maybeThrows
    val y = maybeThrowsToo
    val z = maybeThrowsAsWell
    result(x, y, x)
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    // How do I know which maybeThrows failed?
  }
}
```

The `Future` case works essentially in the same way.

---

Even grouping computations in `List` doesn't help:

```
def func = {
  try {
    val x = maybeThrows
    val y = maybeThrowsToo
    val z = maybeThrowsAsWell
    val list = List(x, y, z)
    result(list)
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    // How do I know which maybeThrows failed?
  }
}
```

---

*Spoiler:* you have to track explicityl which computation failed. It would result in some boilerplate if done with `try/catch`. But luckily with `Future` (and `Try`) the boilerplate isn't that bad:

```
class TaggedException(val idx, exc: Exception)

def tagFailedWithIndex[T](idx: Int, f: Future[T]): Future[T] = 
  future recoverWith { case exc => Future.failed(new TaggedException(idx, exc)) }

val comF = for {
  f1 <- tagFailedWithIndex(0, future1)
  f2 <- tagFailedWithIndex(1, future2)
  f3 <- tagFailedWithIndex(2, future3)
} yield something(f1, f2, f3)

comF onFailure { 
  case exc: TaggedException => "%d computation failed".format(exc.idx)
}
```

*Spoiler* you have to track which computation failed explicitly. It would result in a lot of boilerplate if done with `try/catch`. But luckily there is `Try`, and `Future` behaves even more the same:

```
class TaggedException(val idx, exc: Exception)

def tagFailedWithIndex[T](idx: Int, f: Future[T]): Future[T] = 
  future recoverWith { case exc => Future.failed(new TaggedException(idx, exc)) }

val comF = for {
  f1 <- tagFailedWithIndex(0, future1)
  f2 <- tagFailedWithIndex(1, future2)
  f3 <- tagFailedWithIndex(2, future3)
} yield something(f1, f2, f3)

comF onFailure { 
  case exc: TaggedException => "%d computation failed".format(exc.idx)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Oleg Grenrus for your help. But how do I know if the future is a Future[List[T]] (I updated my question.)

Comment: Amended the answer with spoiler.

Answer (score 5):

## The problem: flatMap combines the Futures into one single Future

You are using `flatMap`, so the futures are nested into one single future.

Your code is

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

val future1, future2, future3 = Future[Any]()

val comF = for {
  f1 <- future1
  f2 <- future2
  f3 <- future3
} yield {
  // something
}

comF onSuccess { ??? }
comF onFailure { ??? }
```

When I apply the de-sugaring rules to your for-comprehension, I get

```
val comF = (future1).flatMap { case f1 => 
  (future2).flatMap { case f2 => 
    (future3).map { case f3 => {
        // something
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can clearly see the use of `flatMap` here. In principle `flatMap` does two things: It applies a function to the result of the first `Future`. This must be a function that maps the result of the first `Future` to another `Future`, i.e. a `Future` nested in the first `Future` (this is the `map` part). Then it 'unnestes' the two `Futures` and merges them in one single `Future` (the `flat` part). On this point, the two `Futures` don't exist any more (from a conceptual point of view; technically they are still there). Instead there is only one 'merged' `Future`.

The two calls to `flatMap` create a new `Future` out of the original three. This is the reason why you cannot find out, which of the three original `Futures` raises the exception: It's none of them. Instead the newly created `Future` runs and raises the exception.

## Solution: Track your progress separately

If you want to know, which steps of your calculation ran before one raised an exception, you must track the progress separately, e.g. through an additional parameter in the `Exception`. Alternatively you can remove `flatMap` and run the individual `Futures` one after the other.

### An example on how to track your progress:

First we create a new exception class, that contains the real exception together with some information, where the exception came from

```
class ExceptionWithOrigin[T](val origin : T, nested : Throwable) extends Exception(nested)

object ExceptionWithOrigin {
  def wrapFuture[T,U](origin : T, f : Future[U]) : Future[U] = {
    f.transform(Predef.identity, new ExceptionWithOrigin[T](origin,_))
  }

  def wrapFuture[U](f : Future[U]) = wrapFuture(f,f)
}
```

For the `Futures` we have no special requirements.

```
val future1,future2,future3 = Future[Any]()
```

We then wrap up the given `Futures` using the helper method from the companion object of our newly created exception class.

```
import ExceptionWithOrigin._

val comF = for {
  result1 <- wrapFuture(future1)
  result2 <- wrapFuture(future2)
  result3 <- wrapFuture(future3)
} yield {
  // something
}
```

When you catch some exception `ex`, you can now just use `ex.origin` to find out where it came from. Of course, the origin is not quite correct. The original `Futures` `future1`, `future2` and `future3` are not really executed. Instead a newly created `Future` runs, created by the `flatMap`. But nevertheless the origin still works.

## A hint about better naming

Btw, you should rename `f1`, `f2` and `f3` to `result1`, `result2` and `result3`. They don't represent a `Future`, but the result of the calculation of each `Future` (the value each `Future` returns).

Answer (score 3):

The venerable @Rit (Brendan McAdams) finally convinced me to try Scalaz with disjunctions in his talk [A Skeptic's Look at scalaz' "Gateway Drugs"](https://speakerdeck.com/bwmcadams/scala-exchange-2014-a-skeptics-look-at-scalaz-gateway-drugs-a-practical-exploration).  Your code would be wrapped in a disjunction and look like this:

```
val comF = for {
  f1 <- future1 \/> "Future 1 failed"
  f2 <- future2 \/> "Future 2 failed"
  f3 <- future3 \/> "Future 3 failed"
} yield {
  // something
}
```

[Related quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22483826/1637003)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to tell between individual failures, you have to handle failures individually. Something like this, perhaps:

```
Future[List[T]] = Future.sequence(
    futures.zipWithIndex.map { case (f, idx) => 
        f.onFailure { case ex => println(s"Future $idx failed with $ex") }
        f
    } 
)
```