# scala futures - how to get result or failure from both futures

Tags: scala, future

I'm using `for` to run 2 futures in parallel. I want to know which succeeeded and which failed in all cases (all should run til completion with either a result or a failure status). Currently I am only able to retrieve a combined success result

I took insperation from here but it doesn't suffice since I don't get the success statuses when a single fails nor the failures of both in cases of both failing [failure in Scala future's for comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945014/failure-in-scala-futures-for-comprehension)

```
case class TaggedException(context:String, val throwable: Throwable) extends Exception(throwable.getMessage)

val f1 = Future {...}.recoverWith {case e:Throwable => Future.Failed(new TaggedException("first one failed", e))}
val f2 = Future {...}.recoverWith {case e: Throwable => Future.Failed(new TaggedException("second one failed", e))}

val combinedResult = for {
  r1 <- f1
  r2 <- f2
} yield (r1,r2)

combinedResult.onFailure {
case e : TaggedException => ... // if both fail I only get the first line in the for
// in case where single fails I only know fail status without the success of the second
}
```

I'm trying to avoid this mess:

```
var countCompleted = 0 ... or some other atomic way to count 
f1 onComplete {
  case Success(value) => {
    ... countCompleted increment ... 
    // handle success
    if both completed {
       // handle returning a status
    }
  }
  case Failure(error) => {
    ... countCompleted increment ... 
    // handle failure
    if both completed {
       // handle returning a status
    }
  }
}

f2 onComplete {
  case Success(value) => {
    ... countCompleted increment ... 
    // handle success
    if both completed {
       // handle returning a status
    }
  }
  case Failure(error) => {
    ... countCompleted increment ... 
    // handle failure
    if both completed {
       // handle returning a status
    }
  }
}
```

Edit : Another version  - Is this a valid approach?

```
def toFutureTry[A](future: Future[A]):Future[Try[A]] = future.map(Success(_)).recover {case t: Throwable => Failure(t)}

    val fa: Future[Try[Blah]] = toFutureTry(f1)
    val fb: Future[Try[Foo]] = toFutureTry(f2)

    val combinedRes = for {
      ra <- fa
      rb <- fb
    } yield (ra,rb)

    combinedRes.onComplete {
      case Success(successRes: (Try[Blah], Try[Foo])) => // all of these cases are success or fails
      case Failure(f: Throwable) => // i think it is unused right?
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `transform` and `zip` like this:

```
val combinedResult: Future[(Try[T], Try[T])] =
  f1.transform(Success(_)).zip(f2.transform(Success(_)))
```

Then you can do:

```
combinedResult map {
  case (Success(v1), Success(v2)) =>
  case (Success(v1), Failure(f2)) =>
  case (Failure(f1), Success(v2)) =>
  case (Failure(f1), Failure(f2)) =>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `flatMap` on `Future[A]` won't help, as it will always short circuit on the first failure produced by one of them, where you really want to accumulate errors.

A solution using `Future.traverse` which will work on arbitrary many `Future[A]` instances:

```
val f1 = Future.failed[Int](new Exception("42")).recoverWith {
  case e: Throwable => Future.failed(TaggedException("first one failed", e))
}

val f2 = Future(42).recoverWith {
  case e: Throwable =>
    Future.failed(TaggedException("second one failed", e))
}

val res: Future[List[Either[Throwable, Int]]] = 
  Future
   .traverse(List(f1, f2)) {
      eventualInt => eventualInt
       .map(i => Right(i))
       .recover { case err => Left(err) }
   }

res.onComplete {
  case Failure(exception) =>
    println(exception)
  case Success(value) =>
    value.foreach {
      case Right(int) => println(s"Received num: $int")
      case Left(err) => println(s"Oh no, err: $err")
    }
}

Await.result(res, Duration.Inf)
```

We can also use a little help from cats with it's `Validated` type:

```
import cats.data.Validated.{Invalid, Valid}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import cats.implicits._
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  case class TaggedException(context: String, throwable: Throwable)
    extends Exception(throwable.getMessage)

  val f1 = Future.failed[Int](new Exception("42")).recoverWith {
    case e: Throwable => Future.failed(TaggedException("first one failed", e))
  }

  val f2 = Future(42).recoverWith {
    case e: Throwable => Future.failed(TaggedException("second one failed", e))
  }

  val res: Future[List[Validated[Throwable, Int]]] = 
    List(f1, f2)
     .traverse(eventualInt => eventualInt
                       .map(i => Valid(i))
                       .recover { case err => Invalid(err) })

  res.onComplete {
    case Failure(exception) =>
      println(exception)
    case Success(value) =>
      value.foreach {
        case Valid(int) => println(s"Received num: $int")
        case Invalid(err) => println(s"Oh no, err: $err")
      }
  }

  Await.result(res, Duration.Inf)
}
```

Will yield:

```
Oh no, err: TaggedException$3: 42
Received num: 42
```

Comment: and without catz :)_

Comment: @AvnerBarr James approach will work, as he's wrapping the internal thunk with a `Try[A]`, and then `flatMap` over that will not short circuit.

Comment: but I'm getting a future as a result of a function call - I need to "insert" the try into it

Comment: I could provide a specific implementation of `List[Future[A]]` to `Future[List[A]]` if you wanted to use that.. but it'll be very specific.

Comment: Is this a valid approach? :

```
def returnsAFuture() = Future {1/0}
  val f3 = returnsAFuture()

  def toFutureTry[T](future: Future[T]) = future.map(Success(_)).recover{case t : Throwable => Failure(t)}
  val sdf: Future[Try[Int] with Product with Serializable] = toFutureTry(f3)
  
  val successFail = f3.map{
    Success(_)
  }.recover {
    case t: Throwable => Failure(t)
  }
```

Comment: @AvnerBarr I've updated my answer to use standard Scala types and functions. See if that works for you.

Comment: can you validate my updated edited answer - I tested locally, seemed to give the desirerd result

Answer (score 0):

With for-comprehensions, as soon as one line fails the code just stops there and any exception is thrown. If `r1 <- f1` throws a Throwable, `r2 <- f2` will never be hit in the first place.

I would personally throw them both in an `Either[Throwable, whatever]`, rather than putting each `.recoverWith` in a `Future.Failed(...)`. This way, rather than just doing an `onFailure` you can do something with any `Left` values you get and do something else with any `Right` values you get. Or you could use `Try/Success/Failure`... Depends what you want to do with the errors though.

I don't know your specific use-case, but if you want to handle each success or failure case individually you could do something like this:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

val f1 = Future(Try(1 / 1))
val f2 = Future(Try(1 / 0))

// for-comprehensions won't fall over when reading a Failure
// as failures don't extend Throwable
val combinedResult = for {
  r1 <- f1 // Success(1)
  r2 <- f2 // Failure(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero)
} yield List(r1,r2)

combinedResult.map { // get inside Future
  f =>
    f.map { // get inside List
      case Success(a) => // do something with success
      case Failure(e: IndexOutOfBoundsException) => // do something with failure
      case Failure(e: ArithmeticException) => // do something with failure
      case Failure(e) => // do something with failure
    }
}
```

I don't personally like using onComplete; I prefer to keep data inside a Future for as long as I can by mapping inside. That's just personal preference though.

Comment: can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a generic example of one way I like to deal with exceptions inside Futures... wrapping them in a Try if you don't have some sort of type class or trait or something can be really helpful if you don't want to deal with the exceptions until later.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work. The result of for-comprehension is a failed future, so ,you have nothing to map over.

Comment: @Dima no it isn't, the result of this for-comprehension is a `Future[List[Try[Int]]]`.

Comment: Oh, I missed the `Try` ... Sorry

Answer (score 0):

~~First of all, you are *not* running your futures in parallel (for-comprehension will run them *sequentially*).~~

**Update** the above isn't true, as mentioned in the comments. I missed that the futures are being created outside of the for-comprehension.

And secondly, as you noticed, if either one of the futures fail, the other one is lost.

To get around the fact that if one of the futures fails, the result of the other is lost, you could "lift" your future values to `Try`:

```
val lifted1: Future[Try[Foo]] = f1.transform(Success(_))
val lifted2: Future[Try[Bar]] = f1.transform(Success(_))
```

Now, you can do something like:

```
 (lifted1 zip lifted2).map { 
   case (Success(foo), Success(bar)) => // both succeeded!
   case (Success(foo), Failure(t)) => // foo succeeded, bar failed with t
   case (Failure(t), Success(bar)) => // guess what!
   case (Failure(t1), Failure(t2)) => // oops
 }
```

If you find yourself doing this often, you might find it useful, "pimp" your futures with the `lift` operation:

```
 object FutureSyntax { 
   implicit class FutureOps[A](val fu: Future[A]) extends AnyVal {
      def liftToTry: Future[Try[A]] = fu.transform(Success(_))
   }
 }
```

So, now if you `import FutureSyntax._`, the above can be written as

```
 (f1.liftToTry zip f2.liftToTry).map { 
    case (Success(foo), Success(bar)) => ... 
    ...
 }
```

You could write the same with a for-comprehension, too, it just would be more verbose. For-comprehension wouldn't be my choice in this case: they are good when processing a sequence of futures, where those later in sequence depend on the results of earlier ones. For processing independent futures, `zip` or `sequence` is usually a better choice.

Comment: *you are not running your futures in parallel (for-comprehension will run them sequentially).* He's creating the futures eagerly before using them in the for-comprehension. There's no sequentiality there.

Comment: yes, they should be running in parallel since created outside of the loop

Comment: Ah, yes. I missed that. Oops.

Comment: you can do: `fu.transform(Success(_))` instead of `fu.map(Success.apply).recover { case NonFatal(t) => 
         Failure(t)`

Comment: @ViktorKlang  I think, you need the second argument, but `fu.transform(Success(_), identity)` works too, yes.

Comment: @Dima I'm refering to the method which has a single argument.

Comment: Ah, yeah ... I am still on 2.11 here :/